# how to launch ext.window, using ext?

Tags: extjs

I want to launch a ext.window in a browser. What is the best way to handle this or do this? The catch is window should use

`Ext.layout.BorderLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window = new Ext.Window({layout: 'border'}).show()`

You'd need to be a bit more specific about your problem to get more specific answer.

Comment: will it open in new browser window? Do i have to give url for it to open? Or does this code opens blank window?

Comment: It opens new Ext window in current browser window (or tab actually). It's empty by default and you need to configure it to do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Can you give me one example please? How i can add stuff to it? Like if i want to add tabs on this window... How will i add it? Do i need to do window. something to add those?

Comment: There are several ways, and basically you just put anything you want to have inside it into `items` config property. Just like you do with any other container. If you need understanding how ExtJS components work I can recommend 'ExtJS in Action' by Jay Garcia. Excellent book.

Comment: Actually all i am trying to do is. Open a window with borderlayout. Then have tabs on the right of the window and pannel on the left. Then between tabs i want to put some form, combobox, etc. I get how to add combobox, forms all that by reading. But i am confused as to how i can accomplish this completely. If you can guide me in right direction i will really appreciate that.